# How to stop background process automatically if app not in touch

Tags: android, service

Now i am going on with to check whether the app is active or not.

For this i had went with the OnPause() and OnResume() i had used this in my BaseActivity which is abstract class for all other Activity.

Now what i need is if my app is not view in the screen other app is running in screen in that case how can i check whether the app is active or not.

For example by using Ontouch() if i didn't touch my app more than 5min it should stop all his background service.

In facebook we will get notification even if we logout or not in use but here what i need it should not show any notification when the app is not in use for 5 min.

If anyone have idea about this please help me friends.

Comment: Create a Handler and run postDelayed with 5 mins at onCreate() of your activity. When your onTouch() is triggered, interrupt the Handler and run a new postDelayed with 5 mins. Then in the runnable you execute the code to abort background processes.

Comment: let me try and know for u